# How to ingest images in Google Earth Engine using Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to upload a folder of .tif files as Google Earth Engine assets. Is there a way to do this without first exporting the .tif files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket? And if so, can it be done in a Python environment using the ee or geemap API? Obviously I could just individually upload them as assets, but I was wondering if the process can be streamlined.

Comment: Check out the [geeup](https://geeup.geetools.xyz/) CLI. It can [upload folders of images](https://geeup.geetools.xyz/projects/image_upload/) as assets.